# How to type Hangul using send_keystrokes

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import win32gui
import pywinauto

def send_msg(msg):
    global program_name
    hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, program_name)
    app = pywinauto.Application(backend="win32").connect(handle=hwnd) 
    program = app[program_name] 
    program.send_keystrokes(msg)

program_name = "  "
send_msg("영어만 작동하네요. 한글이 안돼요")
```

If I type the alphabet it works fine
But when I input Korean, it doesn't work.
Can you teach me how to solve this problem?